# Sort only values greater than zero, and display only first 32 of sorted

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, dynamic, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of form

```
  | value | sort_key |
1 | Foo   | 0        |
2 | Bar   | 1        |
3 | Bizz  | 3        |
```

I need to fill in another field of a different table with sorted values from value, by sort_key, BUT excluding ones where sort_key is zero. Also, this new table should only have the 32 highest(by sort_key) elements.

I have tried `=SORT(range, sort_key's column number, FALSE)` but it of course does not omit 0 values,  nor "cuts" the range to only 32 elements, which I would want it to

Comment: yes, I'll change the tag now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the following meets your need:

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"select A where B <> 0 order by B desc limit 32",0)
```

This selects only column A (could include the sort key if you wanted), sorts it by the sort key in descending order, and limits the result to the first/top 32 values.

If you want the sort key included as well, use the following:

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"select A,B where B <> 0 order by B desc limit 32",0)
```

**Update:**
Okay, JvdV was faster than me!

[image]

Comment: Haha, nice little update =). Great answer! + =)

Comment: Just to add a clarification point - it is possible that when you say "by sort key", that you want them in ascending order by sort key, but excluding zeroes.  Then the formula would be "order by B asc limit 32", but the ascending is the default, so the "asc" can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, assuming your data is in `A2:B`:

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"Select A where B<>0 Order By B desc Limit 32")
```

This would select all values from column A where values in column B are other than 0. It will also internally process and order column A by column B and show a maximum of 32 values.